# Custom wound transformer primary winding appears shorted

Tags: transformer

I am currently building a step down transformer with multiple secondaries and a single primary. The core material is standard silicon steel EI laminations.

The primary is spec'd out to use 127 turns of magnet wire with the secondaries being proportional to that in the normal way for voltages. I have 3d printed a custom bobbin made out of abs plastic.

The problem is after I wind the entire transformer and plug it in for some reason under no load 8 amps of current are drawn on the primary which leads to A LOT of heating requiring me to shut down the transformer to prevent damage. What are some possible reasons for this high current draw when the transformer under max load was designed to draw no more than a single amp on the primary?

EDIT: Detailed Design

The core is made of silicon steel rated to 2T with a center leg width of 22.23mm and a stack height of 90mm.

Primary - 127 Turns of 24AWG

Secondary 1 - 14 Turns of 18AWG

Secondary 2 - 9 Turns of 18AWG

Secondary 3 - 6 Turns of 24AWG

Secondary 4 - 17 Turns - Center tap - 9 Turns - Tap - 17 Turns

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTMq1t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Above is the basic test schematic, just insert the additional secondaries which were also open.

Comment: Please specify more details; which (and how many) laminations, secondary turns, etc. as well a simple drawing of how you've wired the test circuit.

Comment: Is the wire enamal coated? - I know it seems a silly question...

Comment: Yes they are enamaled, will post more details

Comment: Did you measure the primary with RLC meter before adding secondaries? Did you test the primary without the secondaries?

Comment: The primary without the secondaries draws 8A. I don't have an RLC meter but it has a resistance of around 4ohms

Comment: 40 Ohm is its actual impedance, or the one you aimed for?

Comment: Say the core is 10 uH per turn^2, you'll get a primary inductance of 161mH which at 60Hz is an impedance of 60 ohms. At 120V RMS you'll get 2A. Now I don't know what core you are using but it strikes me that 127 turns may be a little light.

Comment: 4 ohms and I cant measure the impedance, I dont have a meter, that was the dc resistance. I wasn't aiming at any impedance

Comment: What would be a more ideal transformer impedance? I thought as the core material I was using had an extremely high saturation I could get by using less windings. I used the following: ` t = V(RMS) / 4.44 / m2 / Hz / T`

Comment: @secretformula I'd say  (and this is a total generalization) 10H - this is an impedance of 3770 ohms at 60Hz and will "take" (with no secondary load) a current of about 32mA from 120V AC RMS 60Hz.

Comment: Is there anyway I could add inductance in series with the transformer to get the required impedance? I have no time to go out and buy new core materials which would be needed due to space constraints with this current design.

Comment: @secretformula, assuming that you plug it in 120V AC RMS, and taking into account DC resistance of 4 Ohm + AC current of 8A, leads to ~11 Ohm of inductor's impedance. Assuming frequency of 60Hz we get ~30mH inductance. I'd say that even air cored inductor of similar dimensions should give more than that. Conclusion: probably you do have a short in your inductor. You could add a big inductor in series, but if you primary is indeed screwed up - you'll (probably) won't get the required functionality

Comment: I will try winding it yet again but I have each layer insulated for its neighbor and the odds of a short seem unimaginable.

Comment: I have an inductance of 246mH in the primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to an error in my calculations, the transformer's impedance was way too low, allowing a large amount of current to flow.